# FixedThreadPool and exception while running a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, threadpool

I have a FixedThreadPool which has 1 slot for thread execution. Is it possible that, if a thread is occupying the slot and throws a non-catched exception, this slot keeps used forever, and the thread executor is not able to execute any new thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. From the documentation of [`ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29):

> If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.